# What's the pro of creating a theocracy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've searched on both wikis and on google itself, but I've found almost nothing about theocracies.

What are the pros and cons of having a theocratic vassal?

Answer (score 1):

A theocratic vassal is, for all intents and purposes, a temple vassal. Most importantly, this means you can have a vassal with a significant amount of land who is still expected to pay you taxes. Their levy contributions, however, may be a little lower.

You'll also find that theocratic vassals tend to be more obedient. They do have an opinion penalty for being of a different type of government but they tend not to be ambitious and very rarely try to rebel or take your title.

As a Catholic, granting temple vassals more titles gives them more eligibility to become a cardinal or even the Pope. They won't become a vassal pope this way but you will get a hefty opinion bonus for supporting them and a pope who likes you is more likely to accept requests.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: However, for catholics, if the clergy vassal has a higher opinion of the pope than you, then you will receive neither taxes nor levies. So your ruler traits will be a bigger factor for your clergy vassals (piety type traits). If your Kingdom or empire is largely governed by theocracies, then you can set up an Anti-Pope or do elective succession (in order to get a dynasty ruler with the most religiously-favorable traits).

Comment: You could also convert to a religion which doesn't have a pope or other religious leader. That way all your religious vassals will always be loyal to you. But keep in mind that this has quite a lot of other implications.